# Combining SAS datasets

Tags: sas, set

I have to create a SAS dataset by taking data from either of the below files :

```
DATA Latest_data;
SET new_table&yday. new_table&Bfryday. append_new&yday. append_new&Bfryday.; RUN;
```

So here among the 4 files present in the SET statement only one of might will exists. So when I am trying to create the Latest_data it throws the an error since the rest 3 datasets are empty. How can I resolve this or what other method can be used.
**&yday** has a value like **30MAY2023** and **&Bfryday** has a value like **29MAY2023**

Comment: Do you want to read all of them if they all exist?  If not which one do you want?

Answer (score 3):

You could just tell SAS to treat a non-existent file as NOT an error by setting the NODSNFERR system option.  Just make sure to set it on again.

Example:

```
1188  options nodsnferr;
1189  data want;
1190    set sashelp.class xy xyz ;
1191  run;

NOTE: The data set WORK.WANT has 19 observations and 5 variables.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.01 seconds
      cpu time            0.01 seconds


1192  options dsnferr;
1193  data want;
1194    set sashelp.class xy xyz ;
ERROR: File WORK.XY.DATA does not exist.
ERROR: File WORK.XYZ.DATA does not exist.
1195  run;

NOTE: The SAS System stopped processing this step because of errors.
WARNING: The data set WORK.WANT may be incomplete.  When this step was stopped there were 0 observations and 5 variables.
WARNING: Data set WORK.WANT was not replaced because this step was stopped.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.00 seconds
      cpu time            0.00 seconds
```

Comment: If you need to know the name of the data set being used, be sure to use the `SET` option `INDSNAME=<automatic-variable>`

Answer (score 2):

This is a good use case of using a conditional macro function to check if each dataset exists. If the dataset exists, then the table will be added to the `set` statement. Otherwise, it will not.

```
DATA Latest_data;
    set %if(%sysfunc(exist(new_table&yday))) %then %do;
            new_table&yday.
        %end;

        %if(%sysfunc(exist(new_table&Bfryday.))) %then %do;
            new_table&Bfryday.
        %end;

        %if(%sysfunc(exist(append_new&yday.))) %then %do;
            append_new&yday.
        %end;

        %if(%sysfunc(exist(append_new&Bfryday.))) %then %do;
            append_new&Bfryday.
        %end;
    ;
run;
```